# What is the difference between StringType and LargeStringType in Apache Arrow?

Tags: apache-arrow, apache-arrow-cpp

According to documentation:

```
class arrow::StringType : public arrow::BinaryType
#include <arrow/type.h>
Concrete type class for variable-size string data, utf8-encoded.
```

```
class arrow::LargeStringType : public arrow::LargeBinaryType
#include <arrow/type.h>
Concrete type class for large variable-size string data, utf8-encoded.
```

How large is considered to be "large"?

What are the differences between the two data types? Why do we need 2 instead of 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String uses signed 32-bit integers for its [offsets/indices](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html#variable-size-binary-layout) so you cannot have a string longer than 2 GiB, and you cannot have an array with more than 2 GiB of data total. LargeString uses 64-bit integers so you can have much longer strings and larger arrays.

Comment: I just discovered that this information is actually in the documentation, but not at the place I'd expect it to be.
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/datatype.html#_CPPv4N5arrow4Type4type12LARGE_STRINGE